# Android - Float - Always 00 after point

Tags: java, android

I want to display the average number in the textview.
however, the output is always the integer.
For example, my input num1 is 2 and 3. the output is 2.00.
input: 2 and 7, the output is 4.00.

here is my code.

```
    <string name="ave">Average: %1$.02f</string> //in strings.xml        

    //in main function
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

    //get the average number
    float average = ( num1 + num2 ) / 2;
    ave_num.setText(getString(R.string.ave, average));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right side of this assignment:

```
float average = (num1 + num2) / 2;
```

consists only of integers.  
So after the addition, the division will give the result of **integer division**.  
This is how the compiler treats mathematical operations between integers.  
Of course you want the result as `float`. 
So do this:

```
float average = 1.0f * ( num1 + num2 ) / 2;
```

By multiplying with `1.0f` (the `f` suffix denotes `float`) you will get the desired `float` result. 
Or:

```
float average = ( num1 + num2 ) / 2f;
```

Comment: 1.0f* is work! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat

```
  float average = ( num1 + num2 ) / 2;
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
  df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

  System.out.println(df.format(average ));
```

or String.format

```
  String average=String.format("%.02f", average )
```

Comment: That won't help because the real problem is integer division, not the formatting

Answer (score 0):

I've already tested this code:

```
float average = ( num1 + num2 ) / 2f;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d)
{
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

or

```
String.format("Value of a: %.2f", a) // for 2 decimal number ex. 1.03

String.format("Value of a: %.3f", a) // for 3 decimal number ex. 1.003

String.format("Value of a: %02d", a) // for 2 didgit ex. 01
```

Comment: That won't help because the real problem is integer division, not the formatting